# De que maneira posso buscar a que pacotes/bibliotecas pertencem as funções de uma rotina escrita em R?

Tags: r, algoritmo-de-busca, packages

Já deixei de utilizar diversas rotinas pelo fato de que os programadores não informam a que pacotes/bibliotecas as funções que estão nestas rotinas utilizam. Sei que muitas destas funções são de autoria do programador e não se encontram em nenhum repositório, mas cogitando que a maioria delas estejam  em pacotes distribuídos nos repositórios livres (CRAN, R-br, ... ) é possível encontra-las. Mesmo assim, procura-las é uma tarefa trabalhosa o que torna-se um problema.

Para contornar este problema quero saber de que maneira posso entrocar um ou os pacotes a que uma função pertence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode começar tentando a busca na ajuda dos pacotes instalados na sua máquina, por exemplo `??"nome_da_funcao"`.

Entretanto, isso só vai funcionar se (i) o pacote estiver instalado e (ii) a função tiver página de ajuda.

Outra solução é buscar diretamente na documentação, pelo RSiteSearch:

```
http://search.r-project.org/
```

Você consegue utilizar a busca diretamente da linha de comando também:

```
RSiteSearch("nome_da_funcao")
```

Existem funções auxiliares como `find` e `getAnywhere` mas elas são ainda mais limitadas, pois somente funcionam se o pacote estiver carregado na seção.

O ideal mesmo é sempre pedir que os comandos de `library` estejam todos especificados no script.

Comment: também gosto de procurar no github fixando a linguagem R. Exemplo: https://github.com/search?l=R&q=function&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 1):

Mais algumas alternativas:

1. Pode parecer óbvio, mas simplesmente pesquisar por "R função" no Google é quase sempre suficiente para funções de pacotes que estão no CRAN, salvo funções com nomes muito simples/repetidos.
2. O site http://www.inside-r.org/ possui a documentação de todos pacotes no CRAN, e normalmente é onde você vai parar se usar o método acima. Mas se não der certo, pode pesquisar diretamente no site.
3. Caso a função seja relacionada a biologia, você pode procurar também no site do [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/). Também é um destino do Google, mas pode ser mais útil diretamente.